# what algorithms does clojure's core.logic use for solving?

Tags: clojure, prolog, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

According to wikipedia, prolog uses [SLD Resolution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SLD_resolution). 
What are the principle algorithms driving the solving in core.logic?

Comment: Did you look at the source?

Comment: Yes. If you have anything to contribute don't by shy.

Comment: @false this question is not a duplicate. It asks for how it works, not for a comparison. The best answer so far sends you off to a comparison, but even the comparison doesn't necessarily provide the fullest answer.

Comment: @matanster: Please read the comment of OP on the answer! Should the comparison not "provide the fullest answer", then please do write a better answer!

Comment: @false, I don't know about you, but I am unable to add an answer, probably because this has been marked as a duplicate.  Perhaps you are right that the other question subsumes this question, but this question is a lot narrow than that one.  Rather than read through a multi-page answer to try to glean the desired information, I think a direct answer to this question would be much shorter.

Answer (score 3):

core.logic is effectively miniKanren. Comparison here:

[What are the main technical differences between Prolog and miniKanren, with respect to logic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467011/what-are-the-main-technical-differences-between-prolog-and-minikanren-with-resp)

Or another explanation here:

http://minikanren.org/minikanren-and-prolog.html

Comment: Thanks, this comparison provides a great window for learning how they work, and for figuring out required readings in logic and theorem proving.