# Data to function: What data would have to be passed to minikanren to get eval?

Tags: function, eval, logic-programming, minikanren, inductive-logic-programming

There is a video where minikanren is used to go from data to programs. That is, given data, it generates the program that generates the data.

So is it possible to generate a universal function such as eval? What data would have to be passed to it?

Comment: I can say more if you link the video, but you might find [this](https://github.com/webyrd/Barliman) interesting

Comment: "running programs backwards" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kS_2_-E_JjU